# scanf reading totally different number

Tags: c, scanf

Here is all the code I have in Visual Studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int input;

    puts("There are 10 seats available on the next flight");
    puts("Where would you like to reserve a seat?");
    puts("Please type 1 for First Class");
    puts("Please type 2 for Economy");

    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == 1) {
        printf("You Typed %d\n", &input);
    }
    if (input == 2) {
        printf("You Typed %d\n", &input);
    }

}
```

But when I run the program I get output that says:

```
There are 10 seats available on the next flight
Where would you like to reserve a seat?
Please type 1 for First Class
Please type 2 for Economy
1
You Typed 6159588
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I get a totally random number every time. Because of this I can't seem to get anything I write after the input to work. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are using pointers with printf?

Comment: Don't send addresses to `printf` unless you have a format specifier expecting one (and you don't). Lose the `&`.

Comment: Simplest of all above: `printf("You Typed %d\n", &input);` --> `printf("You Typed %d\n", input);` VTC as typo.

Comment: Before I was getting an error when I excluded the & and now I'm not. So now it's working fine. That is annoying.

Comment: Before your code was probably using scanf instead of printf by mistake, and now it's not.

Comment: **Turn on your compiler warnings**. It should be able to help you with some easy-to-read diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

What you get printed out is the *address* of the variable `input`, not its value! This is because printf accepts its arguments by value - simply because they can be passed like that. What you need thus is

```
printf("%d", input); // without the ampersand!
```

scanf - in contrast - is fundamentally different. It is going to place a value into a variable you provide to it - and therefore needs a pointer.

Simple example:

```
int n = 7;

void myPrintf(int v)
{
    ++v;
}

void myScanf(int* v)
{
    ++*v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myPrintf(n); // n passed by value, cannot be modified
                 // (but printf does not intend to, either!)
    myScanf(&n); // n will be incremented!
                 // (scanf does modify, thus needs a pointer)
    return 0;
}
```

Back to the roots, though: There is still a fundamental problem: You are passing a pointer, but evaluate it as an int. If sizes of both differ - which is the case on modern 64-bit hardware - you are in trouble. The value then is read from the stack with different size and part of your address actually gets discarded (pointer addresses require `"%p"` format specifier, assuring that the apprpriate number of bytes is read from stack - in case of modern systems 8 vs. 4 for int).